# Having only specific column selectable JTable and/or getting the data from only one column

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jtable

I have a `Swing` program with a `JTable`, and there are two columns: one for names, and one for phone numbers associated with those names. Currently, the program allows for selection of rows, which causes data in both columns to become selected. I want selected data to be output to an array of strings, but only the data from within a certain column (that with phone numbers), no matter how many rows are selected. How would I go about this?

I was thinking of changing `setColumnSelectionAllowed(false)` to `setColumnSelectionAllowed(true)` and allowing a `JHeader` to be clicked to select an entire row, or somehow allowing for `getValueAt(int row, int column)` to be put into an array and only allow for reading of the phone numbers column.

Code for initializing table:

```
        // Initializing the JTable
        String[] columns = {"Student", "Phone"};
        students = new JTable(data, columns);
        students.setGridColor(Color.lightGray);
        students.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 400));
        TableColumnModel columnModel = students.getColumnModel();
        columnModel.getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(100);
        columnModel.getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(100);
        students.setRowHeight(25);
        students.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        students.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
        students.setColumnSelectionAllowed(false);
        students.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
```

Table is made from CSV file as an array:

```
        String[][] myNewArray1 = new String[30][30]; //creates an array
        Scanner myScanner1 = new Scanner(filePath1); //creates a scanner which uses the text file
        int k = 0;
        while (myScanner1.hasNext()) {
            myNewArray1[k] = myScanner1.nextLine().split(",");
            k++;
        }
        return (myNewArray1);
    }

    // Driver method
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File filePath1 = new File("C:\\Users\\cmorl\\IdeaProjects\\CompSciIA\\src\\CompSciIA.csv"); //file path
        String[][] data1;
        data1 = makeArrayFromTxt(filePath1);
        new Database(data1);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 TableModel model =  table.getModel();    
  List <String> data = new ArrayList();
  for (int count = 0; count < model.getRowCount(); count++){
                  data.add(model.getValueAt(count, 0).toString()); //Change 0 with 1 if you want column 2
   }
```

Comment: This code seemed to be working, and now it's not, and I'm not sure how that is exactly possible. But now I'm wondering how the code even was working in the first place, because in the for loop if `count` is less than `model.getRowCount();`, and `count` increases in increments of one, then wouldn't that just print all of the given column's (0 or 1) data, rather than specific selected data? That's what it is currently doing, but again, I remember it working like once or twice. I don't know, maybe that seems incredulous. Maybe code ordering is a factor?

Comment: no. that count is for rows. So for all rows, the code will add to list, the data at column 0 or  1 at the specified row. 

If you already know the selected row and column then you can just call model.getValueAt